# Dev tools not showing insecure content loaded in via javascript

Tags: ssl, https, firebug, google-chrome-devtools

I work with a lot of SSL/https pages that must be 100% secure so the lock is green and not yellow.

It's easy to pinpoint any 'dom level' scripts or images, because console puts out the error 'this page is loading insecure content from *_*_'

The problem is when a secure https script loads NON-https image/script... it doesnt seem to be logged in chrome dev tools console as an error for loading insecure content. The only way to see it is if i manually move the mouse over like 80 different asset links, tracking pixels, etc and making sure it starts with https

Does anyone know a better way of handling this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Firebug you can enable the display of a *Protocol* column. To do so you have to right-click onto the column headers inside the [*Net* panel](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Net_Panel) and click on *Protocol*. Then you can sort by that column by clicking on it's column header.

Doing so it should be pretty easy to spot the insecure request.

Sebastian